# Printing number pattern

Tags: c++

I'm working on a c++ assignment and one of the questions requires me to print this pattern of numbers below:

```
1
223
44365
8864910
44365
223
1
223
44365
8864910
44365
223
1
```

I can see that the first column consists of squares if 2,and i can print it as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  for (int i=0;i<=3;i++){
    cout<<pow(2,i)<<endl;
  }
  for (int i=2;i>=0;i--){
    cout<<pow(2,i)<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

it gives me the output:

```
1
2
4
8
4
2
1
```

but I don't see the pattern the rest of the numbers correspond to. Any help?

Comment: Base on your loop counter, how many numbers do you expect to see?

Comment: @vincent those loops were only meant to print the first column. To give you people an idea of what i'm trying to do here.

Comment: If that is *all* you have been asked to do, what about `std::cout << "1\n223\n44365\n8864910\n44365\n223\n1\n223\n44365\n8864910\n44365\n223\n1\n";`

Comment: Alternatively:  `static const int vals[] = {1,223,44365,8864910};` and then print out elements of that .

Answer (score 3):

[See image for the logic of the pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO3Ml.jpg)

thats basically the logic behind this pattern. once you make this, you can easily invert and then use nested loop to print it twice.

Answer (score 0):

You need Nested loop. Think about formula to get patten, and do in your nested loop, like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int j, i, n=3;
for(j=0;j<=n;j++)
{ // YOU CAN ADD FORMULA
    for(i=1;i<=j;i++)
        {
            // YOU CAN ADD FORMULA
        }
        cout<<"\n";
}

for(j=0;j<=n;j++)
{ // YOU CAN ADD FORMULA

    for(i=0;i<=n-j;i++)
        {
           // YOU CAN ADD FORMULA
        }
        cout<<"\n";
}

getch();
return 0;
}
```

Improve by your self

Comment: Trouble is, I think the OP can't work out the formula (and neither can I).